# Question about Milnor's talk at the Abel Prize

Tags: differential-topology

I don't quite follow the rough outline Milnor gives of the fact that the 7-sphere has different differentiable structures. The video is available [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kQaUCDFvbjA), and the slides he used can be found [here](http://www.math.sunysb.edu/~jack/MilnorOslo-print.pdf).

Here's what I got from the talk. Unless otherwise stated, all manifolds are compact, orientable smooth (most of the time I state these hypotheses explicitely anyways), and $M$ is an ($n$-dimensional) manifold. Homology and cohomology are taken with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$.

- By a theorem of Whitney, $M$ embeds in $\mathbb{R}^{n+k}$ from which we get a Gauss map $g:M\rightarrow G_n(\mathbb{R}^{n+k})\subset G_n$, where $G_n(\mathbb{R}^{n+k})$ is the grassmannian manifold of $n$-planes in $\mathbb{R}^{n+k}$, and $G_n$ is the colimit of those grassmannians, i.e. the grassmannian of $n$-planes in $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$. All Gauss maps $g$ (viewed as maps $M\rightarrow G_n$) are homotopic, and we obtain a well defined homology class $\langle M\rangle=g_*\mu\in H_n(G_n)$. The letter $\mu$ stands for the fundamental class of $M$.
- If $M$ is a compact orientable topological manifold of dimension divisible by $4$, say $\dim~M=4k$, it comes equipped with a symmetric bilinear form given by the cup product in dimensions $2k$:
  $$H^{2k}(M)\times H^{2k}(M)\rightarrow H^{4k}(M)\simeq \mathbb{Z},~(x,y)\mapsto x\cup y$$
  This form must kill torsion, so we get a quadratic form on the finitely generated free abelian group $H^{2k}(M)/\mathrm{Torsion}\simeq \mathbb{Z}\oplus\cdots\oplus\mathbb{Z}$, and we can define its signature (as a real quadratic form). The signature of the manifold $M$ is then defined as $\sigma (M)=p-q$ where $p=\#$ of positive eigen values and $q=\#$ of negative eigenvalues.
- Going back to the differentiable case, we define the Pontrjagin numbers of $M$ by looking at the cohomology ring of $G_n$. This ring is concentrated in dimensions that are multiples of $4$ and has one generator $p_i\in H^{4i}(G_n)$ for each $i\geq 1$, so that all $1,p_1, p_1^2,p_2,p_1^3,p_1\cup p_2,p_3,\dots$ generate the cohomology (plus some torsion elements). We then define the Pontrjagin numbers of $M$ by evaluating these cohomology classes on the homology class $\langle M\rangle$. This gives potentially non zero numbers provided $M$ has dimension $4k$. In particular, if $M$ has dimension $8$ and is smooth, compact, orientable, there are two Pontrjagin numbers: $p_1^2(M)$ and $p_2(M)$.
- By a theorem of Hirzebruch, the signature of $M$ (with $\dim~M=4k$) ought to be a polynomial with rational coefficients in the Pontryagine numbers of $M$, and Milnor tells us that in case $\dim~M=8$,
  $$45\sigma(M)=7p_2(M)-p_1^2(M).$$
  This is somehow related to oriented cobordism. Apparantly, two smooth oriented compact manifolds $M$ and $N$ of the same dimension are cobordant iff $\langle M\rangle=\langle N\rangle$. I understand that the signature is a cobordism invariant, so that it extends to a homomorphism $\sigma:\Omega(n)\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ where $\Omega(n)$ is the group of oriented cobordisms, and that since cobordism classes are determined by $\langle M\rangle\in H_n(G_n)$, there ought to be a linear relation between the non torsion bits of this homology class (which can be read off the Pontrjagin numbers) and the signature. **The main idea of the proof will be to calculate $$\frac{1}{7}(45\sigma(M)+p_1^2(M))$$ for some eight dimensional manifold, to observe that it is not an integer thus showing that its boundary, while homeomorphic to the $7$-sphere, cannot be diffeomorphic to it.**

Part of my confusion stems from here. Milnor considered $7$-dimensional smooth compact orientable manifolds $M$ that are the total space of a locally trivial fibre bundle with fibre $\mathbb{S}^3$ over $\mathbb{S}^4$. He was able to show explicitely that some of these $M$ were homeomorphic to the $7$-sphere by constructing explicit Morse functions with exactly two critical points. However, he found that some of these smooth manifolds that were topological $7$-spheres could not be diffeomorphic to the $7$-sphere. He then (as I understand it) calculated $\frac{1}{7}(45\sigma(E)+p_1^2(E))$ for some $8$ dimensional manifold (Which one?) and found that the result was not an integer.

Could you help me understand how he got to exotic $7$-spheres? What manifold $E$ would one consider? Why is the result a non integer? and how could it be a non integer? since in order to make sense of $p_1^2(E)$ in the first place we need it to be smooth, and then $\frac{1}{7}(45\sigma(M)+p_1^2(M))$ must be equal to $p_2(M)$ which is an integer.

Comment: If you don't get any answers here in a day or so, this question could be suitable for Math Overflow.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The method in his slides differs from his original paper. First I will explain Milnor's original construction of exotic $7$-spheres, from his article

- *On manifolds homeomorphic to the $7$-sphere*, Annals of Mathematics, Vol. 64, No. 2, September 1956.

I'll answer your question about his construction mentioned in the slides after that.

---

First, he defines a smooth invariant $\lambda(M^7)$ for closed, oriented $7$-manifolds $M^7$. To do this, we first note that every $7$-manifold bounds an $8$-manifold, so pick an $8$-manifold $B^8$ bounded by $M^7$. Let $\mu \in H_7(M^7)$ be the orientation class for $M^7$ and pick an "orientation" $\nu \in H_8(B^8,M^7)$, *i.e.* a class satisfying
$$\partial  \nu = \mu.$$
Define a quadratic form
$$H^4(B^8,M^7)/\mathrm{Tors} \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z},$$
$$\alpha \mapsto \langle \alpha \smile \alpha, \nu \rangle,$$
and let $\sigma(B^8)$ be the signature of this form. Milnor assumes that $M^7$ has
$$H^3(M^7) \cong H^4(M^7) \cong 0,$$
so that
$$i: H^4(B^8,M^7) \longrightarrow H^4(B^8)$$
is an isomorphism. Hence the number
$$q(B^8) = \langle i^\ast p_1(B^8) \cup i^\ast p_1(B^8), \nu \rangle$$
is well-defined. Then Milnor's $7$-manifold invariant is
$$\lambda(M^7) \equiv 2q(B^8) - \sigma(B^8) \pmod 7.$$
Milnor shows that $\lambda(M^7)$ does not depend on the choice of $8$-manifold $B^8$ bounded by $M^7$.

Now let us turn to the specific $7$- and $8$-manifolds that Milnor considers. As you noted, he looks at the total spaces of $S^3$-bundles over $S^4$. The total space of such a bundle is a $7$-manifold bounding the total space of the associated disk bundle. $S^3$-bundles over $S^4$ (with structure group $\mathrm{SO}(4)$) are classified by elements of
$$\pi_3(\mathrm{SO}(4)) \cong \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}.$$
An explicit isomorphism identifies the pair $(h,j) \in \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ with the $S^3$-bundle over $S^4$ with transition function
$$f_{hj}: S^3 \longrightarrow \mathrm{SO}(4),$$
$$f_{hj}(u) \cdot v = u^h v u^j$$
on the equatorial $S^3$, where here we consider $u \in S^3$ and $v \in \mathbb{R}^4$ as quaternions, *i.e.* the expression $u^h v u^j$ is understood as quaternion multiplication.

Let $\xi_{hj}$ be the $S^3$ bundle on $S^4$ corresponding to $(h,j) \in \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$. For each odd integer $k$, let $M^7_k$ be the total space of the bundle $\xi_{hj}$, where
\begin{align*}
h + j & = 1, \\
h - j & = k.
\end{align*}
Milnor shows that
$$\lambda(M^7_k) \equiv k^2 - 1 \pmod 7.$$
Furthermore, he shows that $M^7_k$ admits a Morse function with exactly $2$ critical points, and hence is homeomorphic to $S^7$. Clearly we have
$$\lambda(S^7) \equiv 0,$$
so if
$$k \not\equiv \pm 1 \pmod 7,$$
then $M^7_k$ is homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic to $S^7$, and hence is an exotic sphere. In particular, $S^7$, $M^7_3$, $M^7_5$, and $M^7_7$ are all homeomorphic to one another but all pairwise non-diffeomorphic.

---

Now, in the slides, the space $E$ should be the total space of the disk bundle associated to an $S^3$ bundle $\xi_{hj}$ over $S^4$ with
\begin{align*}
h + j & = 1, \\
h - j & = k
\end{align*}
for some odd integer $k$, as described above. Then $E$ is an $8$-manifold with boundary $\partial E$ homeomorphic to $S^7$. Now, if $\partial E$ is *diffeomorphic* to $S^7$, then we can glue $D^8$ to $E$ along their common boundary via a diffeomorphism
$$f: \partial E \longrightarrow S^7$$
in order to get a *smooth* manifold
$$E' = E \cup_f D^8.$$
If $f$ is not a diffeomorphism, then $E'$ is not necessarily smooth. So in showing that
$$p_2(E') \notin \mathbb{Z},$$
Milnor proves by contradiction that no such diffeomorphism $f$ can exist, since Pontrjagin numbers of a manifold are integers. So in that case $\partial E$ would be homeomorphic to $S^7$ but not diffeomorphic, and hence an exotic $7$-sphere.

Comment: Thank you for this illuminating answer. For the last part, I think there is a typo when you say that *$E$ should be the total space of the $S^3$ bundles $\xi_{hj}$ over $S^4$*, do you mean the disk bundle?

Comment: @OlivierBégassat: That was indeed a typo, and I did indeed mean the associated disk bundle. The error has been fixed.

Comment: Dear Henry, In your fifth last line, should "not nec. a homeo." read "not nec. a diffeo"?  Regards,

Comment: @MattE That is correct. I've edited that part of the post now. Thanks.

Comment: I understand $\lambda (M_k^7)\neq 0$ is telling us "something", but why that "something" has to be non-existence of diffeomorphism between $M_k^7$ and $S^7$?